# any Virtual Ipad/Iphone applications for PC that has network connections?

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, xcode-simulator

I am looking for a virtual emulation of an Ipad or Iphone that I can run on a PC machine so I can create video tutorials on things such as setting up our corporate email  or how to connect the devices to our network. I have found some applications via Google and youtube, but so far they do not support a network connection.  I know there are android emulators that do this, but haven't found an IOs one. If anyone could point me in the direction of one it would be greatly appreciated.

I would prefer free software, but am willing to pay as long as its in a reasonable price range.

I got the answer below, but I found a pretty promising site for anyone who happens to be looking for the same thing. [Miricast and AirPlay emulation](http://www.airserver.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there are no emulation / simulation engines that I've seen that work well enough to run tutorials in anything resembling a smooth manner, your least expensive option would be to get a cheap secondhand iPad and then use AirPlay emulation software on the PC to capture the screen and make your videos.

You could even save money by taking static screen captures and then animating them on the PC.

The only simulator that even comes close to what you need runs on OS X and is part of Xcode delivered from Apple. You could probably virtualize that, but the cost there is more than buying cheap used iOS hardware. Even an iPod touch is often good enough for walk through videos on basic settings for corporate users.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I will be looking into your solution.

Comment: again thanks for the help. I found a cool site http://www.airserver.com/ by looking up AirPlay emulation.  It seems to be everything I am looking for and at a pretty cheap price.

Comment: @JeffreyQuinn Yes - that one gets lots of positive comments here. I haven't used it, but it's likely all you'll need to record iOS from the PC.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your PC to an Airplay server(just like AppleTV) via some App.
you can download [airserver](http://www.airserver.com) trial version